# How to calculate the integral of this fraction

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So I have this fairly complicated fraction, and I am trying to find its antiderivative.

$$
\int \frac{7xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2} dx
$$

I am not sure where to start. I was thinking using integration by parts, but then I tried substituting it with $u$'s:

$$
u = 1+2x, du = 2 dx \to dx=\frac{du}{2} \\
= \int \frac{\frac{7u-7}{2}e^{u-1}}{u^2}\color{red}{\frac{ du}{2} }\\
= \frac{7}{4}\int \frac{e^{u-1}}{u} du - \frac{7}{4}\int \frac{e^{u-1}}{u^2} du
$$

But now I am stuck and I can't go any further. Can someone please guide me through this problematic integration? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$
= \frac{7e^{-1}}{4}\bigg\{\color{red}{\int \frac{e^{u}}{u} du} - \int \frac{e^{u}}{u^2} du\bigg\}\\
= \frac{7e^{-1}}{4}\bigg\{\color{red}{\frac{e^{u}}{u}-\int \frac{-e^{u}}{u^2} du }- \int \frac{e^{u}}{u^2} du+c\bigg\}\ \text{integration by parts}\\
=\frac{7e^{-1}}{4}\frac{e^{u}}{u}+c
=\frac{7e^{u-1}}{4u}+c
=\frac{7e^{2x+1-1}}{4(2x+1)}+c
=\frac{7e^{2x}}{4(2x+1)}+c
 $$

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am having hard time figuring out what did you substitute for $u$. Can you explain it more?

Comment: i will in the answer now

Comment: i use integration by parts in the red term

Comment: $\int fg'dx=fg-\int gf'dx$

Comment: Yes but I was willing to know what equals to $u$ in your calculation.

Comment: He started from where you left the problem. So $u=2x+1$.

Comment: $g'=e^u$ and $f=\frac{1}{u}$

Comment: Okay I understand that part now, but then what did you do for $\int \frac{-e^u}{u^2}$ ?

Comment: Thanks! I see it now, you are awesome!

Comment: @Semsem - Wait but then from $$\frac{7e^u}{2eu}$$ I get $$\frac{7e^{2x}}{4x+2}$$, and the answer I got from WolframAlpha is $$\frac{7e^{2x}}{8x+4}$$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: $e^{-1}*e^u=e^{u-1}$ in the first step in your comment

Comment: it should be $\frac{7e^{u-1}}{2u}$ in your comment

Comment: Isn't $e^{u-1}$ the same as $\frac{e^u}{e}$ and I should get the same answer in the end?

Comment: both answers agree

Comment: i will complete it for you

Comment: I believe somewhere in between a $\frac{1}{2}$ was lost.

Comment: This half is lost your step when you caculated $dx=du/2$ you

Comment: @Semsem - I see your edited answer, but the problem is $\frac{7e^{2x}}{2(2x+1)}$ is not correct according to WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 notice the last comment

Comment: @Semsem - Oh thanks! I see it now.

Comment: i complete on your answer which shuold be multiplied by 1/2 i can this step in your Q, one moment

Answer (score 5):

First, let's pull out the constant factor $7$.  The denominator being a square suggests trying to find functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ such that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right] = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2} = \frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}.$$  This in turn suggests trying $g(x) = 1+2x$, so that the numerator becomes $$(1+2x)f'(x)- 2f(x) = xe^{2x}.$$  If $f(x) = h(x) e^{2x}$ for some polynomial $h$, then $f'(x) = h'(x)e^{2x} + 2h(x) e^{2x} = (h'(x)+2h(x))e^{2x}$, hence $$xe^{2x} = (4xh(x) + (1+2x)h'(x))e^{2x}.$$  This is easily satisfied with the choice $h(x) = 1/4$, so $f(x) = e^{2x}/4$ and an antiderivative is $$7 \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} + C = \frac{7e^{2x}}{4(1+2x)} + C.$$  Of course, this method doesn't always work, but it is an interesting approach.

Comment: It is interesting indeed I did not even think of ever trying this

Comment: How did you get $xe^{2x} = (4xh(x) + (1+2x)h'(x))e^{2x}$ from the above? I was following but this line confuses me.

Comment: If $f(x) = h(x) e^{2x}$, then $f'(x) = (h'(x) + 2h(x))e^{2x}$, and $(1+2x)f'(x) - 2f(x) = (4xh(x) + (1+2x)h'(x))e^{2x}$, which we equate with the numerator of the integrand, assuming that it is the derivative of some quotient of functions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d(e^{2x}f(x))}{dx}=e^{2x}f'(x)+2e^{2x}f(x)=e^{2x}[f'(x)+2f(x)]$$

If we choose $\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{2A}{(1+2x)^2}, f(x)=-\frac A{1+2x}$

$$\frac{d\left[e^{2x}\cdot\frac{-A}{1+2x}\right]}{dx}=e^{2x}\left[\frac{2A}{(1+2x)^2}-2\frac A{1+2x}\right]=2Ae^{2x}\cdot \frac{1-(1+2x)}{(1+2x)^2}= \frac{-4Ax e^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}$$

Compare with the given integral to find $-4A=7$

Answer (score 1):

d/dx(7*e^2/4*(2x+1))=7xe^2/x(1+2x)^2
=>d(7*e^2/4*(2x+1))=(7xe^2/x(1+2x)^2)dx
Hence you get the required integral.